# Is there a jquery tooltip plugin that allows you to configure the length and thickness of the arrow/spike?

Tags: jquery, jquery-tooltip

I am aware of [Beauty Tips](https://www.lullabot.com/files/bt/bt-latest/DEMO/index.html) but it does not appear as though the project has been touched or supported in a couple years. I've been scouring the web and "XX great JQuery tooltip plugins" lists, but all of them seem to position the bubble a set distance from the target (on whichever side you specify) and have a fixed arrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.opentip.org/ has the nicest and most configurable jQuery tooltips I could find.  They let you specify those parameters.  I use them in my own projects.  Go to their main page and mouse over STEMS to see a demo.

Comment: Awesome! exactly what I was looking for. Very easy to use. Extremely configurable. Thanks!!